# Security for WebApi and sites - Asp WebAPI

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, xamarin

SO I write project.
It is will:
1) Site - app
2) Site - Admin control panel
3) Mobile App (with Xamarin)
4) API

SO now I think what is the best practice and better way

**Option #1:**

2 sites: **App** site and **Admin** site - like 2 **ASP MVC Applications**
and 
2 apis: **Admin** api for admin site and api for **app** site + **mobile requests**

**Option #2:**
1 site and 1 api

Why I think about 2 apis?
Because hucker will see where going requests from app site. And he will can try huck it....but all remove and billing logic will store on admin api - whick will have another ip........

why 2 sites - for store ip for admin api in site whik only me can see

Sorry for english grammar guys

P.S 1 more question:

I junior in xamarin and in mobile app in general.

So i dont know how to set token or somethink for auth with web api

If somebody can send me link for tutorial xamarin + asp webapi authentication - its will nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a seperate projects for API,If security is your issue. Use OWIN (Token based authentication) for your API's which is more secure than basic authentication.

OWIN Auth is significant, If you are using your API's in angularjs application.

[Have a look at this CodeProject Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/876867/ASP-NET-Web-Api-Understanding-OWIN-Katana-Authenti)